# CGAL Alpha_shape_2 extract boundary vertices

Tags: c++, cgal

Appreciate if you could assist me with alpha_shape_2. I`m new with CGAL.

I`m trying to extract boundaries from 2D data.

```
Alpha_shape_2 alpha(lp.begin(), lp.end(), FT(1000), Alpha_shape_2::GENERAL);
```

Alpha_shape_2 call works perfectly. But, I`m confused on how to extract only boundary vertices.

Much appreciate some example.

Comment: What do you call boundary vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get points, but they are not sorted:

```
std::vector<Point> result;

for(Alpha_shape_2::Alpha_shape_vertices_iterator it =  alpha_shape.Alpha_shape_vertices_begin();
    it != alpha_shape.Alpha_shape_vertices_end();
    ++it){

    Alpha_shape_2::Vertex_handle handle = *it;
    Point p = handle->point();
    result.push_back(p);
}
```

You need start read [manual on official website](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/index.html) to understand some concepts. The simple examples in CGAL does not have that much explanation and functionality. You need get more familiar with actual structure of CGAL.

This is how to get segments by edges. But segments not sorted too, you will need do it by yourself.

```
for(Alpha_shape_2::Alpha_shape_edges_iterator it =  alpha_shape.Alpha_shape_edges_begin();
    it != alpha_shape.alpha_shape_edges_end();
        ++it){

    CGAL::Kernel::Segment segment = alpha_shape.segment(*it);

    Point p1 = segment.vertex(0);
    Point p2 = segment.vertex(1);
    // so here you will get p1 and p2 of segment, which is part of shape.

    .....

}
```

You will get something like this:
[image]

That is after my sort function (sorry can't share. but it's not so complicated to write):
[image: CGAL ALpha Shape 2D]

**UPDATE**
I found [this source](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/driving_distance/src/alpha_drivedist.cpp), maybe will be helpful.